# Fail to add chef extensions for VM in resource manager template

Tags: templates, powershell, azure, chef-infra

I am trying to create a windows VM with chef client by ARM (Azure resource manager) template. I find an example template in github:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/chef-extension-windows-vm

```
    {
    "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'),'/',variables('chefClientName'))]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
    "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
    "location": "[variables('location')]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Chef.Bootstrap.WindowsAzure",
        "type": "ChefClient",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1201.12",
        "settings": {
            "client_rb": "[parameters('client_rb')]",
            "runlist": "[parameters('runlist')]"
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
            "validation_key": "[parameters('validation_key')]"
        }
    }
}
```

I deploy this template in powershell, storageAcount/vNet/IP/NIC/VM are created successfully. But the chef extension create fail with the following error:

```
New-AzureResourceGroupDeployment : 3:44:51 PM - Resource Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions
'myVM/chefExtension' failed with message 'Extension with publisher 'Chef.Bootstrap.WindowsAzure', type 'ChefClient',
and type handler version '1201.12' could not be found in the extension repository.'
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureResourceGroupDeployment -Name $deployName -ResourceGroupName $RGName -T ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCommand
```

How can I create a VM with chef by ARM template ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failure is cause by wrong "typeHandlerVersion", "1201.12" is no longer available. "1207.12" works fine. To get the available extension information, use the following powershell command:
Get-AzureVMAvailableExtension  | select ExtensionName,Publisher,Version,PublishedDate